# How to fix datatype mismatch to predict images using my trained model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

I trained a CNN, but I'm unable to use it to make predictions.
All of my images are in a folder

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("C:\Sid\CNNs\MoonRocks.h5")
import os
filepath = "C:\Sid\Projects\LunarMoonRocks\DataSet\Test Images"

for img in os.listdir(filepath):
    img_path = os.path.join(filepath, img)
    img_array=cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array=cv2.resize(img_array, (480, 480)) 
    img_tbp = new_array.reshape(-1, 480, 480, 1)
    prediction = model.predict([img_tbp])
```

This code shows the error

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType uint8 not in list of allowed values: float16, bfloat16, float32, float64
```

I tried to change the image type to float32 using

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_tbp)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
```

But that showed the error

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

How do I get my model to predict the images in the folder?

Comment: Can you provide the **full** error message please?

Comment: @HuwThomas the full error message is hundreds of lines long

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f10c6ebeb584> in <module>
      7     new_array=cv2.resize(img_array, (480, 480))
      8     img_tbp = new_array.reshape(-1, 480, 480, 1)
----> 9     prediction = model.predict([img_tbp])
     10     break

Here's the beginning of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode_jpeg` is used to decode the contents of image file which is read in binary format. You have already read your image file using OpenCV and OpenCV reads the file in NumPy format. Had you made use of [`read_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/read_file), then you should have used `decode_jpeg`.

Now coming to your problem, you could have converted your `uint8` image to floating type either by just using `tf.cast` operation as you had done it, but you have most likely forgotten to normalize your image from the range of [0, 255] in `uint8` to [0, 1] in float. So you could have directly converted your image to float and bring the number's value in range of [0, 1] using:

```
image = image / 255.0
```